# Function dictionary without specifying parameters

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary that uses strings as keys and `Action` functions as values.

Is there a way to define the dictionary without specifying the parameters of each key's function? For example, say I have a function `foo(int a, string b)`. Is it possible to assign `dict['test'] = foo`?

I apologize if this question has been asked already -- I wasn't sure what to search for.

Comment: you could have dict["test"] = (a,b)=>foo(a,b); but I am not sure that is what you want. It is not clear

Comment: Do you want to store functions with different parameters in the dictionary side-by-side, or would a `dict` always be homogenous? `Dictionary<string, Action<T1, T2>>` should work if the latter (and it makes sense to have generic parameters in your circumstance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `Delegate` instead of typed function. You'll call them with `DynamicInvoke()` and parameters can be passed with an array. In short:

```
Dictionary<string, Delegate>() _delegates;

void Test1(int a) { }
void Test2(int a, int b) { }

void SetUp() {
    _delegates = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
    _delegates.Add("test1", Test1);
    _delegates.Add("test2", Test2);
}

void CallIt(string name, params object[] args) {
    _delegates[name].DynamicInvoke(args);
}
```

Try it:

```
CallIt("test1", 1);
CallIt("test2", 1, 2);
```